# How to rewrite url with apache

Tags: apache, url, webserver

I have a website given to me to host and it has many files and folder, that I put inside a folder TEST. Right now, the folder resides in the root of my apache so that the web is accessible by going to http://mydomain/TEST.

However, my boss asks me to show the website by navigating to http://mydomain. How do I do this? I can write a html redirect page that directs http://mydomain to http://mydomain/TEST but the full URL will still show in the user's browser.

Comment: http://google.com/?q=htaccess+redirect

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this with an alias. In your Apache config file, use:

```
Alias / /var/www/mydomain.com/TEST/
```

This assumed /var/www/mydomain.com is the path to your site's source folder, but in looking at it, this is unnecessary. You can simply point your site's path to this folder instead of the /var/www/mydomain.com folder. Unless you want to be able to access both the original site and the TEST site at the same time.

Using Redirect is an option, also, but I would use an Alias, instead. Redirecting is for when an old location is moved to a new one.

Comment: For some reason Alias /abc /Test works, but Alias / /Test doesn't. Any ideas? It says: You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Comment: Dismiss my previous comment. It just redirects me to the test page (Apache welcome page). Any ideas?

Comment: I just got this working on my testing environment. You need to replace TEST with the full path to your test folder. I will update the answer.